# Nested Template Functions as Parameters

Tags: python, c++, templates

In Python, there is a very simply way of decorating a function such that you can add additional functionality before and/or after a function. In its most simple form, it looks like this:

```
from random import SystemRandom
from time import time
import functools

rdev = SystemRandom()

def time_function(func):
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def run(*args, **kwargs):
        start = time()
        ret = func(*args, **kwargs)
        print("Took {:0.5f}s".format(time()-start))
        return ret
    return run

@time_function
def foo():
    x = [rdev.randint(1, 1000) for _ in range(10000)]
    sorted(x)

foo()  # prints "Took 0.04239s"
```

I wanted to write something with similar functionality in C++. I would like to pass a function with arbitrary parameters and return types into a function and have it perform some action. This is what I came up with:

```
#ifndef TIMEIT_H
#define TIMEIT_H
#include <string>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#if defined(_WIN32)
#include <Windows.h>
namespace timeit {
    unsigned long gettime(void) {
        return GetTickCount();
    }
}
#elif defined(__linux__)
namespace timeit{
    unsigned long gettime(void) {
        return 0; // implement later
    }
}
#endif

namespace timeit {
    template <typename> struct timer_s;

    template<typename... Args> // this is required for any void function
    struct timer_s<void(Args ...)> {
        std::function<void(Args ...)> func;
        timer_s(std::function<void(Args ...)> f) : func{ f } {}
        void operator()(unsigned long &time, Args ... args) {
            unsigned long start = gettime();
            func(args ...);
            time = gettime() - start;
            return;
        }
    };

    template <typename T, typename... Args> // this is for any other return type
    struct timer_s<T(Args ...)> {
        std::function<T(Args ...)> func;
        timer_s(std::function<T(Args ...)> f) : func{ f } { }
        T operator()(unsigned long &time, Args ... args) {
            unsigned long start = gettime();
            T ret = func(args ...);
            time = gettime() - start;
            return ret;
        }
    };

    template<typename T, typename... Args>
    timer_s<T(Args...)> timer(T(*func)(Args ...)) {
        return timer_s<T(Args ...)>(std::function<T(Args ...)>(func));
    }
}
#endif//TIMEIT_H
```

This is working rather well. For example, I can time mostly any function with the following:

```
static std::random_device rdev;

unsigned int foo(size_t size){
    std::vector<unsigned int> nums(size);
    std::mt19937 rand(rdev());
    std::generate(nums.begin(), nums.end(), rand);
    std::sort(nums.begin(), nums.end());
    return nums.back(); // return largest number
}

int main(){
    //foo(0xffff); // normal call
    unsigned long foo_time = 0;
    auto t_foo = timeit::timer(foo);
    unsigned int largest = t_foo(foo_time, 0xffff); // stores time
    std::cout << "Took " << foo_time << "ms\nLargest number: " << largest << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

The trouble arises when I try to time a templated function such as `std::sort` directly. I can only do it if I specify the exact type. I supposed I am wondering if C++ is capable of doing nested template deduction. I want it to deduce which form of std::sort I am using and change the implementation of t_sort dynamically:

What I am currently doing:

```
static std::random_device rdev;

int main(){
    std::vector<unsigned int> nums(size);
    std::mt19937 rand(rdev());
    std::generate(nums.begin(), nums.end(), rand);
    auto t_sort = timeit::timer(std::sort<std::vector<unsigned int>::iterator>);
    unsigned long sort_time = 0;
    t_sort(sort_time, nums.begin(), nums.end());
}
```

What I would like:

```
static std::random_device rdev;

int main(){
    std::vector<unsigned int> nums(size);
    std::mt19937 rand(rdev());
    std::generate(nums.begin(), nums.end(), rand);
    auto t_sort = timeit::timer(std::sort); // this line is different
    unsigned long sort_time = 0;
    t_sort(sort_time, nums.begin(), nums.end());
}
```

Is this possible? My initial reaction is probably not, but if not, why?

Comment: How about `timer([&](){return std::sort(nums.begin(), nums.end());});` syntax ?

Comment: I'm not necessarily against it, but I think it does make it a bit less pythonic. I know that's a terrible, terrible way to look at it, but I like the simplicity of wrapping a function. I suppose my question is whether or not deduction can occur when using the t_sort function as opposed to when passing in the std::sort function.

Comment: However it looks like I've found the answer to my question: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/wp/html/oct97/template.html#temp.arg.template

Answer (score 1):

`std::sort` is not a function but a function template,

One solution is to any accept Functor instead:

```
namespace timeit {

    template <typename Functor>
    struct timer_s {
        Functor func;
        double time = 0;
        timer_s(Functor  f) : func{ f } {}

        template <typename ... Ts>
        auto operator()(Ts ... args) {
            struct Finally {
                ~Finally() {
                    time = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>
                              (std::chrono::system_clock::now() - start).count();
                }
                double& time;
                std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock> start;
            } finally{time, std::chrono::system_clock::now()};
            return func(std::forward<Ts>(args)...);
        }
    };

    template<typename F>
    timer_s<F> timer(F f) {
        return timer_s<F>(f);
    }
}
```

And then call it:

```
// Generic lambda to wrap std::sort and call the correct one.
auto t_sort = timeit::timer([](auto b, auto e){ return std::sort(b, e); });

std::vector<int> v {4, 8, 23, 42, 15, 16};

t_sort(v.begin(), v.end());
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8f892c4076ec7c79)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you've found your answer that something doesn't exist in c++ quite like what python provides, but I'd like to address your question of 'why?' in the context of variadic templates.

The error message you're probably getting is *"cannot determine which instance of overloaded function "std::sort" is intended"* and that's because you aren't actually passing a specific function pointer to `timer`. `Sort` only becomes a specific function when you declare its type, as an un-specialized template it's just the idea of a function. The compiler will deduce the types for `T` and `Args` in `timer` based only on the specific function and arguments you use, so a specific function is necessary. You've got this nice dynamic-typing idea of delaying that specification until later when you actually pass the arguments to `t_sort`. The compiler needs to know what specialized timer should be used when you initialize it with the constructor.

A way to get the types infered for `sort` could be to pass everything to the `timer` constructor (delaying execution execute of the timer for later). Surely the types for `sort` can be inferred from something like this:

`auto t_sort = timeit::timer(std::sort, nums.begin(), nums.end());`

where the factory looks like

```
template<typename T, typename... Args>
timer_s<T(Args...)> timer(T(*func)(Args ...), Args...)
{
    return timer_s<T(Args ...)>(std::function<T(Args ...)>(func), Args...);
}
```

We'd like the compiler to look inside the timer method and see that the `Args...` are of type `std::vector<unsigned int>::iterator` so clearly that is what should be used for the inputs to the function pointer which means that `sort` should be specialized on `std::vector<unsigned int>::iterator`. When the compiler looks at the method signature, it associates the `Args...` parameter to the iterator types and sees that the function needs to take those same types. And this works!

```
template<typename ... Args> // this is required for any void function
struct timer_s<void(Args... )> {

    std::function<void(Args ...)> func;
    std::tuple<Args...> m_args;


    timer_s(std::function<void(Args ...)> f, Args... args)
        : func{ f }, m_args(std::forward<Args>(args)...)
    {
    }


    void operator()(unsigned long &time) {

        unsigned long start = gettime();
```

//          func(std::get(m_args)...); //more on this later
            time = gettime() - start;

```
        return;
    }
};


template<typename... Args>
timer_s<void(Args...)> timerJBS(void(*func)(Args ...), Args... args)
{
    return timer_s<void(Args ...)>(std::function<void(Args ...)>(func), std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

and then you could totally use

`auto t_sort = timeit::timer(std::sort, nums.begin(), nums.end());`

Okay, so this compiles with MSVC (VS2015) and the goal of using std::sort without specifying parameters is achieved. There is a catch though and that's the evaluation of `func` (which I commented out). For some reason I get `error C3546: '...': there are no parameter packs available to expand` which seems to have been due to a bug in earlier version of the compiler. Some sources seem to say it's been fixed others say it's only on the roadmap. I think figuring this out is outside the scope of the question, which was essentially about passing std::sort to a factory function that produced a lazy evaluating wrapper. I hope this is okay for now, if you can't figure out how to get around the compiler error maybe try posting another question. Also, maybe try using some other compilers, I didn't do that.

A final thought, there might be another way to do what I've outlined by binding the parameters to the function within the template, making `sort` explicitly specialized. I think the pattern would more-or-less follow what I've written though, with the only differences being within the timer_s struct.